# What is the easiest way to merge two flv videos?

Tags: java, video, merge, flv

what is the easiest way to merge two flv videos into one?
Would be awesome if its possible without command-line-tools like ffmpeg.

It would be great if someone knows a simple java solution =)

(on the server side)

Comment: Do you want it server or client side?

Comment: merge as in concatenate or merge as in overlapped? And if the latter... With color keys or transparency?

Comment: server side is preferred ;) and I'ld like to concatenate them :)

Comment: It's difficult to understand how you plan to do something on the server side without using a command-line tool.  Do you mean you'd prefer to use a Java library?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want it server side or client side?

1. You can simply play one after the other, using a flv player that has a playlist.
2. You can use avidemux to manualy merge the two
3. The ffmpeg command for the server side process is really simple:

   ffmpeg -i joined.flv -vcodec copy -acodec copy final.flv

Comment: 1 and 2 won't work because it has to run on the server.
And 3 is not really preferred because I have to test it locally on xampp and windows and I really dont want to kill myself by trying to get ffmpeg running on that stuff :P

Comment: ffmpeg -i joined.flv -vcodec copy -acodec copy final.flv

thsi will not work even

Answer (score 1):

According to ffmpeg FAQ:

> Some formats allow you to directly
>   append video data to existing video
>   files. The easiest would be to use one
>   of these formats as intermediate
>   conversions, append files as desired,
>   and finally convert to format of
>   choice:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.avi -sameq intermediate1.mpg
ffmpeg -i input2.avi -sameq intermediate2.mpg
cat intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg > intermediate_all.mpg
ffmpeg -i intermediate_all.mpg -sameq output.flv
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying [avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/).  It understands FLV, is easy to use and you can easily append videos to each other and save them out in the same or different formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to append two FLV's from Java code, you can find source code (using Xuggler) [here](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Concatenating_Two_Files).